# Web API 2 routing - Route attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

Question is regarding defining custom routes with the `Route` attribute.

I know that in the `WebApiConfig` class you always define the default route,

```
configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("API Default", "api/{controller}/{id}",
  new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

What I cannot get working is when I want to pass another parameter. I know I can do this (*code below is defined underneath the default route listed above*):

```
    //configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    //    name: "GetBrandImagePaths",
    //    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{type}");
```

But I'd rather, instead of defining all these routes in the `WebApiConfig` file, use custom routing. **However, if I do not have the commented out code above in the file, I get a 404.** Thus leading me to believe the custom `Route` is not even being looked at.

```
public class HelperApiController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/helperapi/{id}/{type}")]
    public string GetBrandImages(int id, string type)
    {
        .....
    }
}
```

How can I have it so I can use routes defined in the `WebApiConfig` file, AND defining custom routes inside individual API controllers.

Note that this project is also a MVC project (not just WebApi). Is there something I'm missing, doing incorrectly etc? I know there's numerous posts out there defining how to pass multiple params, but I think my question is a little more specific on to why one works and not the other.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to call `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()`.

This will parse all the `Controller` classes and derive the routes from the attributes.

I would not mix this with the standard routing.

Comment: So if I add that call, does that mess up other default routes? (action results, etc)? Would it be safe to say that using `config.MapHttpAttrubteRoutes()` is only for straight WebApi projects?

Comment: No, it doesn't overwrite any routes you put in manually. However, don't then decorate those `Controller` classes with any routing attributes otherwise you will get duplicate and potentially conflicting routes. I've only ever used the routing attributes for WebApi projects so can't comment on their suitability with MVC.

Comment: So if I don't decorate any other controllers (non-Api) w/ the `Route` or `RoutePrefix` then they'll still route to the correct endpoints?

Answer (score 7):

[Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

> **Enabling Attribute Routing**
>
> To enable attribute routing, call **MapHttpAttributeRoutes** during
>   configuration. This extension method is defined in the
>   **System.Web.Http.HttpConfigurationExtensions** class.
>
> ```
> using System.Web.Http;
>
> namespace WebApplication
> {
>     public static class WebApiConfig
>     {
>         public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
>         {
>             // Web API routes
>             config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
>
>             // Other Web API configuration not shown.
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Attribute routing can be combined with convention-based routing. To
>   define convention-based routes, call the MapHttpRoute method.
>
> ```
> public static class WebApiConfig
> {
>     public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
>     {
>         // Attribute routing.
>         config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
>
>         // Convention-based routing.
>         config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
>             name: "DefaultApi",
>             routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
>             defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
>         );
>     }
> }
> ```